# Ruby - Get the second most recent file from a directory?

Tags: ruby, getfiles

I have this piece of script to acquire the most recent file in a directory

```
dir=Dir.glob("./logs/*").max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}
```

I would like to also acquire the second most recent file from the directory. What could I write to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do as below using **Ruby 2.2.0**, which added an *optional* argument to the methods `Enumerable#max_by`, `Enumerable#min_by` and `Enumerable#min` etc.

```
Dir.glob("./logs/*").max_by(2) {|f| File.mtime(f)}
# gives first 2 maximun.
# If you want the second most recent
Dir.glob("./logs/*").max_by(2) {|f| File.mtime(f)}.last
```

[**max_by(n) {|obj| block } → obj**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by)

> If the `n` argument is given, minimum n elements are returned as an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
dir = Dir.glob("./logs/*").sort_by { |f| File.mtime(f) }
puts dir[-2]
```

or

```
dir = Dir.glob("./logs/*").sort_by { |f| File.mtime(f) }.reverse
puts dir[1]
```

[`.sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) will return array of files sorted by `mtime` from oldest to newest, so you can access most recent file with `dir[-1]`(last array element), the second most recent with `dir[-2]` etc. Or you can revert array and use `dir[0]`, `dir[1]` etc. correspondingly.