# Most recent file from a directory with Python

Tags: python, list, date, directory

```
import os
fish=os.listdir("H:\Comu\Solo")
print(fish)
```

The result is:`['lamba_20081104.pdf', 'conal_20070918.pdf', 'apialas_20220628.pdf']`

the result is a list of the three file in the directory and my wished final result is: 20220628

I am not able to proceed...

The characters of the file to be taken are from -12 to -4

The result represents the date of the younger file (28.06.2022) in the directory "H:\Comu\Solo", because the number are date! In contrast with [Ruby - Get the second most recent file from a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636874/ruby-get-the-second-most-recent-file-from-a-directory), in my case is the name-code of the file that suggests me the date!

Someone can write the script to obtain 20220628?

thank you very much

Comment: Regex? `re.findall(r"\d+", file_name)` or `re.findall(r"(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})", file_name)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in one line:

```
max(fish, key=lambda x: x.split("_")[1].split(".")[0])
```

Python max accepts an argument(`key`) that will return your custom max function.

as @sniperd said,you can also use regex in the `key`:

```
max(l, key=lambda x: re.findall(r"\d+", x))
```

Comment: That's actually very clever!  I was going regex route.

Comment: @sniperd Thanks for the suggestion. I add it to my answer.

Comment: @simone100 Your welcome. please check the gray button beside and turn it to green.

Comment: is it right now?